# Convert coroutine to finite state machine (FSM) and vice versa?

Tags: generator, yield, state-machine, coroutine, fsm

I'm trying to find a generalized way to convert a coroutine written in a language like go, python or javascript to a finite state machine (FSM).  I need this in order to integrate several state machines into one large one, because humans tend to be able to follow a thread of instructions more easily than jump through transitions.  These show equivalent examples in both but no way to translate between them:

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/08/29/co-routines-as-an-alternative-to-state-machines/

http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/soc/coroutine/coroutine/finite_state_machines.html

So far, the closest thing I found is [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) but it only seems to convert a series of regular expressions to FSM, similar to how lex or yacc work.

If there is no existing tool to do this with coroutines, is there one for generators?  Perhaps these create FSMs internally that I could use:

http://almostobsolete.net/coffeescript-generators.html

https://www.npmjs.org/package/regenerator

Or does someone know of a general strategy to walk through a coroutine, follow the yields and create a call tree that could be converted to a FSM using goto or a switch command?  It's ok if this only works on a subset of the language, for example with no structures, function calls or includes, which makes me wonder if perhaps the output of a parser would work.

I would also like to be able to do the opposite - convert a FSM to a coroutine but this is not as critical.

Update: this came up in the side links after I posted this.  Actors have similarities with coroutines, so perhaps it's possible to translate coroutines to actors to FSMs: [Finite State Machine and inter-FSM signaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441077/finite-state-machine-and-inter-fsm-signaling?rq=1)

Comment: Hi, my Coffeescript Generators code won't help you, it's just a syntax thing (it relies on the JavaScript target supporting generators). Check out Google's Traceur Compiler for an example of converting ES6 JavaScript generators into FSMs to support ES5: https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler